# How To Display That an Array is Full

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple code that asks for the name, age, and gender of at most 5 patients. After each patient, it should ask to input another patient or return to main menu. Once 5 have been input into an array, there should be a prompt to the user that the array is full.

My problem is the code asks for name,age and gender 5 times upfront, and does not give any indication the array is full. How would I change the code to reflect that and still save the inputs? (Code below).

---

```
class MainClass
{
    enum Gender { female, male }
    struct Record
    {
        public string _Name;
        public int _Age;
        public Gender _Gender;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //title 
        Console.Write("\t\t\t\t\tPatient Records\n");
        string selection = "";
        Record[] patients = new Record[5];
        GetRecords(patients);
        Console.Write("a. Add\n d.Display\ns. Stats\nq. Quit");
        Console.Write("Your selection: ");
        selection = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (selection)
        {
            case "a":
                GetRecords(patients);
                break;
            case "d":
                break;
            case "s":
                Stats(patients);
                break;
            case "q":
                //CUtility.Pause();
                break;
        }
    }

    static void GetRecords(Record[] patient_rec)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < patient_rec.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient_rec[i]._Age);
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            patient_rec[i]._Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter your gender (female or male): ");
            Gender.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient_rec[i]._Gender);
        }
    }

    static void Stats(Record[]patient_rec)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I am voting to close this because you state you don't know why it asks you 5 times to but you call the method `GetRecords(Record[] patient_rec` then you have a for loop the length of the Record[] what do you expect..? I would highly suggest you learn how to use the debugger, set breakpoints and step thru the code..

Comment: you are also calling the `GetRecords() again in the switch statement.. this needs some serious rethinking / debugging..

Comment: @MethodMan We are required to create an array with 5 locations, so that part cannot be changed. Is it possible to move the for loop to another location so it can update each time?

Comment: `TryParse` returns `true` or `false` depending on the success or failure of parsing the `string`. It's probably a good idea to use the result of the method otherwise you've introduced a bug into your code.

Comment: @V.M - I really don't understand your reply to MethodMan. Can you re-explain?

Comment: you are required to create the array with 5 locations but doesn't mean you can't refactor your code to work based on the requirement.. so what I am saying is take the time to think about the problem and think outside the box

Comment: @Enigmativity What I understand is that because the array has 5 locations, it must cycle through the prompts 5 times through the for loop. However, we are instructed to ask name,age,gender only if user selects "a. Add" again. I'm not sure how to do that without cycling through the array.

Comment: @V.M - What do you think should happen when someone hits `a` (Add)? What behaviour do you think that your code should do?

Comment: @Enigmativity it should provide the input options only once, return them to the main menu or exit, and then repeat until the array is full. that is the ideal code ...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to make your code a little easier to read - and more robust.

Try this:

```
static void GetRecords(Record[] patient_rec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < patient_rec.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Record {0} of {1} entry", i + 1, patient_rec.Length);
        patient_rec[i] = new Record()
        {
            _Age = AskInteger("Enter your age: "),
            _Name = AskString("Enter your name: "),
            _Gender = AskGender("Enter your gender (female or male): "),
        };
        string ask = "";
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ask) || (ask.ToLower()[0] != 'y' && ask.ToLower()[0] != 'n'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Continue? yes or no (then hit enter)");
            ask = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (ask.ToLower()[0] == 'y')
        {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you. Input completed.");
}
```

To make this work you need these three input functions:

```
private static int AskInteger(string message)
{
    int result;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    while (!int.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return result;
}

private static string AskString(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return input;
}   

private static Gender AskGender(string message)
{
    Gender result;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    while (!Gender.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is only set to go to the size of the array, so logically you could show a message after the loop (this will get hit when the loop finishes).

If you were controlling your array access in a `while` loop then just compare your indexer `i` to the length of the array (`patient_rec.Length`), if it equals or exceeds the length then show the message.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a simpler way:

```
  enum Gender { female, male }
    struct Record
    {
        public string _Name;
        public int _Age;
        public Gender _Gender;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //title 
        Console.Write("\t\t\t\t\tPatient Records\n");
        IList<Record> patients = GetRecords(5);
        SchedulePatients(patients);
    }

    static void SchedulePatients(IList<Record> patients)
    {
        Console.Write("a. Add\n d.Display\ns. Stats\nq. Quit");
        Console.Write("Your selection: ");
        string selection = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (selection)
        {
            case "a":
                patients.Add(GetRecord());
                SchedulePatients(patients);
                break;
            case "d":
                break;
            case "s":
                Stats(patients);
                break;
            case "q":
                //CUtility.Pause();
                break;
        }
    }

    static IList<Record> GetRecords(int amount)
    {
        IList<Record> patients = new List<Record>();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            patients.Add(GetRecord());
        }

        return patients;
    }

    static Record GetRecord()
    {
        Record patient = new Record();
        Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient._Age);
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        patient._Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your gender (female or male): ");
        Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient._Gender);

        return patient;
    }

    static void Stats(IList<Record> patients)
    {
        foreach (var patient in patients)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Name: ", patient._Name, " Age: ", patient._Age, " Gender: ", patient._Gender));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to meet the requirements with the smallest change possible, you  just need to add the bit about prompting the user.

```
static void GetRecords(Record[] patient_rec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < patient_rec.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient_rec[i]._Age);
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        patient_rec[i]._Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your gender (female or male): ");
        Gender.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out patient_rec[i]._Gender);
        Console.Write("Enter another (Y/N)? ");
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        if (s.ToUpper() != "Y") return;
   }
   Console.WriteLine("You've entered the maximum number of records.");
}
```

Comment: Not seeing the problem. What is the issue, downvoter?